# What if PHP sessions are already started?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I'm making somewhat of a "module" that gets included into another unrelated PHP application. In my "module" I need to use sessions. However, I get the 'session has already been started...' exception. The application that my "module" is included into is starting the session. If I cannot disable sessions in this application, what are my options? I'd like to use Zend_Session, but it seems upon first glance that it is not possible. However, maybe there is another way? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I've managed to get disable sessions on the "parent", but I still don't know if there is a way to use Zend_Session when a session has already been started. I guess there is not. If there is, I'll post back here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With PHP’s session implementation, there can only be one session at a time. You can use [`session_id`](http://php.net/session_id) to check if there currently is a session:

```
if (session_id() === '') {
    // no current session
}
```

Now if there is already an active session, you could end it with [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/session_write_close), change the session ID’s name with [`session_name`](http://php.net/session_name) to avoid conflicts, start your session, and restore the old session when done:

```
$oldName = session_name();
if (session_id() !== '') {
    session_write_close();
}
session_name('APPSID');
session_start();

// your session stuff …

session_write_close();
session_name($oldName);
session_start();
```

The only problem with this is that PHP’s session implementation does only send the session ID of the last started session back to the client. So you would need to set the transparent session ID (try [`output_add_rewrite_var`](http://php.net/output_add_rewrite_var)) and/or session cookie (see [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie)) on your own.

Comment: But then he must still be careful to not interfere with the session variables of the other application.

Comment: But what if I want to start my session as such:
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('session');

Comment: @sims: Sorry, I’m not familiar with Zend_Session_Namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a custom "name" parameter for your application.

The default is `PHPSESSID`. You can change it to `PHPSESSID_MYAPP` to avoid conflicts with the other app.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code before you want to use the Session feature:

```
@session_start();
```

Comment: @Sims It is called `shut up operator`

Comment: Ahh, that thing. I don't use that. And, it will not help since I'm not starting the session via session_start(); but via $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('session');

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with other sessions and, the @ operator is just bad practice in this case. It adds overhead and makes debugging and development harder.